# How to implement notification service using Django Channels in a chat application?

Tags: django, websocket, notifications, chat, django-channels

I am working on chat application based on django, but for **real time notifications** and **chatting**, I plan on using ***django channels***.
The problem is that apart from documentation there are hardly any resources available to get in-dept knowledge of the concepts.

Can anyone suggest a way to implement notifications in my application as when a user receives a message, he/she gets notified(using *websockets* concept).

Also, I plan on using channels as a way to display which of the **users are currently online**.

Models are as follows :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    online = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Dialog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name="self")
    reader = models.ForeignKey(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.name + " - " + self.reader.name

class Message(models.Model):
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender.name + " : " + self.text
```

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now. I would be grateful if anyone can suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance.